# Django rest framwork POST request gives error of forbidden

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I first want to say that yes, I have looked for answers far and wide. This is a very common error. It's a headache and hopefully, there is just a small mistake I've overlooked. Registering a user works, while logging in a user gives:

```
Forbidden: /api/login
[17/Nov/2022 19:37:51] "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 403 32
```

From what I'm reading it's all about permissions, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUzgZrS_piQ

In settings.py I have for instance:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'posts',
    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

In Views.py I have:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .models import User

#Create your views here.
class RegisterView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)


class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']

        user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found!')

        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password!')

        return Response({
            'message': 'Success'
        })
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Urls.py for the sub-app 'users'

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import RegisterView, LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('register', RegisterView.as_view()),
    path('login', LoginView.as_view()),
]
```

And this is the serializer.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

If there is any question about other files and data in my Django project, I'll happily provide it.

I've tried to search for the error and to see what the solution is for others. Permission seems to be the key to fixing this. I thought I had given the permission in the settings.py file.

I'm expecting that get a successful message while logging in as a registered user, through postman, by providing the email and password.

Comment: Show us the `urls.py` file also.

Comment: Have you checked the web server error log for relevant messages?

Comment: Can you add the `UserSerializer` class?

Comment: _I thought I had given the permission in the settings.py file_ What exactly does that mean?

Comment: @JohnGordon I've added the code from my urls.py file

Comment: The code weirdly actually works now. And I can't really explain why. I'll update you if the error comes back. But basically, the server does not give a 403 response forbidding me to do a post request. 
Thank you all for trying to help.